# What solution to use in order to visualize journald/syslog logs via a Web UI (e.g. self-hosted web app, web page or plugin for Nagios and friends)

Tags: logging, system-monitoring

I am running a single virtual, private root server (VPS) and finally managed to setup all daemons to nicely log to syslog. All logs are collected by journald and organized into sylog facilities (mail, auth, local0, ..., local7) to my liking.

I wonder if there is any web application, web page or maybe a plugin for one of the well-known monitoring solutions (e.g. Nagios and friends) which can visualize the logs via a web UI.

It doesn't need to be anything fancy. I don't need automatic event handling, alerts, etc. It would be totally sufficient if the solution reads its input from journald (e.g. something like `journalctl --priority <level> --since -<time span> --facility <facility> --output <format>`), parses the information and converts it into an HTML table. Configuration can be static, it is not necessary to have an interactive web page. The option to have multiple tables for different input filters (e.g. one table per facility, plus one table which collects everything with severity error or higher) would be nice.

My primary use case is to check my server logs for anything suspicious once in a while without the need to login via SSH.

I am already considering to write my own PHP script, but maybe there is something ready to use.

Comment: Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. There is [softwarerecs.se] for that.